# Dynamic content type of table cell

Tags: sapui5

I get data from a database, make a model out of it and bind to a table.

I have a problem with one databse field that contains dataURL of the image or "Not Available" if no image is present.

The problem is that depending on the database field value, the cell of the table should be sap.m.Image or sap.m.Text.

And I can't get it to work.

Here is the relevant code part:

```
var signatureData = {};
signatureData.item = "Signature";
signatureData.value = data.signature;

var oModelSignature = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModelSignature.setData(signatureData);
var oSignatureTable  = sap.ui.getCore().byId("reportDetailsSignature"); 
                oSignatureTable.setModel(oModelSignature);

var oSignature;
if(data.signature == "Not Available"){
    oSignature = new sap.m.Text({text: "{value}"});
}else{
    oSignature = new sap.m.Image({src: "{value}", width: "7%", height: "7%"});
}

oSignatureTable.bindItems("/", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells : [ new sap.m.Text({text: "{item}"}),
             oSignature,]
}));
```

I have my table empty with "No data".

Comment: does this help you? you can work with some kind of visibility-flag --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802498/sapui5-otable-one-row-as-a-link-others-as-textview

Comment: @zyrex, Yes, something like that. The problem is that in `sap.m.Column` there is no `template` (or at least I don't know about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my code was the absence of an array in my `signatureData` object.
After I added the above object into an array which is included in another object, the data appeared in the table.

Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/sijufiwuqu/1/edit?html,output). 
If the value of `signature` key is a data URL of the image (or a link to it), the image is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're getting the value from `data.signature` only once, that will be the value your template will work with, regardless of whatever values it may have further in your model

A better approach will be to use a `HBox` as a template, with both an `Image` and a `Text` control, and using a formatter (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0.html) you toggle the visibility for either of them.

*(Forgive me for using XML syntax for the view, as that's my preferred style. But you can adapt to JS View easily)*:

EDIT: As an exercise for myself, I have created a running Code Snippet below.

```js
// The UI5 controller
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit : function(oEvent) {

        // a model with dummy data. Values are either empty or contain a URL
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({
            rows : [
                { value : "sap-icon://syringe",    col2 : "Value 2",  col3 : "Value 3",  ol4 : "Value 4" },
                { value : "",                      col2 : "Value 6",  col3 : "Value 7",  col4 : "Value 8" },
                { value : "sap-icon://account",    col2 : "Value 10", col3 : "Value 11", col4 : "Value 12" },
                { value : "sap-icon://chalkboard", col2 : "Value 14", col3 : "Value 15", col4 : "Value 16" },
                { value : "sap-icon://e-care",     col2 : "Value 18", col3 : "Value 19", col4 : "Value 20" },
                { value : "",                      col2 : "Value 22", col3 : "Value 23", col4 : "Value 24" }
            ]
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oModel);

    },

    // Formatter for icon visibility
    setIconVisible : function (sValue) {
        return !!sValue;
    },

    // Formatter for text visibility
    setTextVisible : function (sValue) {
        return !sValue;
    }

});

// Code needed to place XML view into 'uiArea' DIV element
sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<!-- bootstrapper -->
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<!-- here the magic will be shown -->
<div id="uiArea"></div>

<!-- The XMLView definition -->
<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View 
      controllerName="view1.initial"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >
        <Table id="tbl" inset="true" multiSelect="true"   selectionMode="MultiToggle" mode="MultiSelect"
        items="{/rows}">
            <columns>
                <Column>
                    <Text text="Col1" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Text text="Col2" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Text text="Col3" />
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <!-- Notice how the cell contains a HBox with an Icon and Text control -->
                        <!-- Visibility will be toggled using the formatter function for both -->
                        <HBox>
                            <core:Icon src="{value}" visible="{path:'value', formatter:'.setIconVisible'}" />
                            <Text text="No data"     visible="{path:'value', formatter:'.setTextVisible'}" />
                        </HBox>
                        <Text text="{col2}" />
                        <Text text="{col3}" />
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! Unfortunately, for now, I don't fully understand it. Can you explain what is happening inside `setIconVisible()` and `setTextVisible()`? What those exclamation marks do exactly? If I understand properly, one of those `visible` properties of `Icon` and `Text` should be `true` and the oner one `false`?

Comment: That is just some basic javascript really... One exclamation mark ('not') returns an inverted boolean (or in this case, converts a non-boolean to an inverted boolean), and double exclamation marks ('not not') returns a boolean (or in this case, coerces a non-boolean to a boolean). And since the one formatter returns the opposite of the other formatter (! vs !!) it basically toggles the visibility state. *(Therefore I believe it is paramount to learn the language (Javascript) first and thoroughly, before diving into one of its frameworks (UI5))*

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I haven't seen yet the use of `!` with a string outside logic operators like `if` or `while`. And you're totally right - if someone wants to play hockey, he needs to learn how to ice-skate. My problem is that I have to do both things simultaniously.